# JavaPOS creating jpos.xml file

Tags: java, usb, thermal-printer, javapos, pos

New to JavaPOS and want to manipulate a POSPrinter using JavaPOS.

Have installed my printer and it's actually choosen as main printer in my OS.

The problem is that i don't know how to write the jpos.xml file and found no documentation about that, i know well that for some companies as Epson, they provide a software to generate automaticlly a jpos.xml file but my printer is a Xprinter and there's no such thing in there website.

How can i do to make this xml file ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaPOS is not completely device independent software for general purpose.

In order to operate a certain device with JavaPOS, it is necessary for the vendor of the device to provide corresponding JavaPOS control.

If there is no JavaPOS control for the printer you are using, only the jpos.xml file does not work.

If the vendor of the device provides the corresponding JavaPOS control, the description method of jpos.xml should be described in that explanation document.

Please check that the vendor of the printer provides JavaPOS control.

Otherwise, switch to the printer of another vendor that provides JavaPOS control, or print directly using OS's API and printer control sequence, not JavaPOS.